# Statically linking OpenSSL with M2Crypto

Tags: python, openssl, m2crypto

[M2Crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/bin/view/Projects/MeTooCrypto) uses the standard

```
python setup.py [build|install]
```

step to build and install the module.  distutils/setuptools allows for some tweaking, but I can't seem to find a way to statically link OpenSSL into the module - there doesn't appear to be any facility to make this change.

Is there any way to build M2Crypto with a statically linked OpenSSL?  (I am willing to bail on `setup.py` and do it by hand if that's the only way, would just like to query if anyone has tackled this before I go and spend hours solving an already solved problem).

Comment: What platform(s) are you using?  And can you say why you want to static link when many platforms strongly discourage it?

Comment: Platforms are linux and win32.  Our export waiver from the commerce department requires that openssl not be replaceable by the end user by swapping out the library, so we can't use shared linkage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the static link libraries for OpenSSL (ssleay32, libeay32), which you might have to build yourself. On Windows you'll have to change setup.py to include some more libraries, e.g.:

```
-self.libraries = ['ssleay32', 'libeay32']
+self.libraries = ['ssleay32', 'libeay32', 'crypt32', 'user32', 'gdi32', 'kernel32', 'ws2_32', 'advapi32']
```

Works for me.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try this.  I *have* the static libraries, but possibly hiding the shared ones will help.

Comment: I've edited your answer to reflect actually don't need `zlib`, but you do need `crypt32`.  Otherwise it was correct from the start.